# С помощью чего вы ведете дела?

Tags: планирование

Я - разработчик, имею постоянно несколько проектов, нужно как-то следить за их состоянием. Расскажите, какие методики и/или ПО вы используете для решения этой проблемы. Голова, к сожалению, не резиновая, многое со временем забывается.
Пользовался одно время MyLifeOrganized, но что-то не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я пользуюсь lightining для thunderbird.

Все просто. Есть два разных типа единиц планирования:

1) event - он привязывается к конкретному времени (скажем с точностью до четверть часа) - это всякие совещания(совместно координируемые события), личные напоминалки по времени(позвонить Васе в 15-00, поход в налоговую - крайняя возможность завтра в 10-00) и т.п.

2) task - это как правило требует упорядочивания не по времени, а по приоритетам - это просто список конкретных задачек(для того чтоб хорошо получалось эти задачки должны быть не длинее дня на исполнение - т.е. надо научиться хорошо дробить большие задачки)

Две эти единицы планирования позволяют нагрузить рабочий конвейер в виде вашей головы и рук. Но ваша голова должна своевременно пополнять конвейер тобишь план. Тут мне известно два подхода к наполнению: задачи рождающиеся по ходу(сразу в список), и задачи планируемые в конце недли, к примеру.

Но! Хочу сразу сказать, этих средсв (которые есть в программах типа MyLifeOrganized) не достаточно для отслеживания "состояния" или прогресса по проекту. Они не для этого, они для эффективной загрузки вашего личного конвейра.

А для отслеживания прогресса существуют проджект мэнеджеры) - это такие специальные люди) со специальной задачей отслеживать процессы в реальной жизни. Боюсь с программкой решающей эту задачу будет туго). Правда сами проджект менеджеры могут использовать в своей работе разные программки для разных целей. Но хочется сразу сказать, что это отдельный человек и ему платят отдельные деньги. Т.е. для Вас как для разработчика - заниматься отслеживание прогресса - это все равно, что устроится еще на одну работу. Как бы трудно. Учитывая то, что Вы еще и студент к тому же, вроде как. Т.е. тройная нагрузка. Вобще, если нет нормального менеджмента в той компании, где Вы работаете - советую сменить компанию)).

Comment: Если бы все так было просто, как пишут в книгах. В том же труде Хенка Рейнвотера - "Как пасти котов" рассказывалось о взаимоотношениях с программистами, автор показывал как нужно организовать труд софтварной фирмы, но, к сожалению, в большинстве российских контор инженер должен уметь всё: общаться с клиентом, распределять задачи, проектировать систему, кодировать и многое другое... Но за ответ огромное спасибо, попробую применить.

Comment: По поводу "инженер должен уметь". Я работал в конторе из 100 человек. С организацией труда програмиста по типу "универсальный солдат"(кстати я служил в армии два года рядовым со схожим функционалом типа "универсальный солдат"))). Сейчас я работаю в конторе из 100 человек с разделением функционала по ролям в команде. Ну что я могу сказать: в первом случае контора загнивает и причина отсутствие мэнеджмента, во втором - контора растет, причина - наличие вменяемого мэнеджмента.

Comment: универсальные солдаты всегда пригодятся :D

Answer (score 1):

**Google Docs + Google Calendar** для ведения проектов и **BlackBerry Calendar** для мелких дел. 
При разработке используется **Redmine**.

Answer (score 0):

miniplan для дома (бесплатен), megaplan для проэктов (90 деревянных в месяц).

1. удобный интерфейс
2. разбивка дел по времени, важности и т.д.
3. возможность оповещ по sms и почте
4. доступность из любого места по инету

Cначала попробовал, а затем конкретно подсел на эти сервисы.

Comment: А у них клиента нету? А то веб-интерфейс меня немного напрягает. =( Использую evernote так не могу работать с веб-интерфейсом совсем почему-то

Comment: Нет, пока клиента нет. Но лично мне и был нужен веб планировщик. Чтобы можно было достучаться с любого места.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще-то, конечно, важен род деятельности! Я себе сам пишу программы через тот же Excel. Использую его как редактор...

Comment: Тут вопрос о системах для тайм-менеджмента и управления проектами. Если я вас правильно понял вы всё это делаете в excel'e, для меня слишком сурово :-)

Comment: Очень четкое определение "слишком сурово"! Это напряжно, но только на первых порах... Даже со старыми версиями 2003 и 2007 можно консолидировать кучу информации и определить свои цели!


Comment: так можно и в блокноте вести дела, если вы говорите что используете для этого excel. Хотя бы немного расскажите про сам процесс, как сделал это @a_s

Comment:  ...ну вот проектирование заключается во многом на шаблонах.Я всего то навсего использую Excel как компилятор...Остальное задаётся тех. характеристиками.. 

Comment: Что-то вы страшные вещи говорите...

Comment: в Excel ведь есть встроенный компилятор скриптов, так что TuLaLaNiO просто использует его как графический интерфейс)

Answer (score -1):

Всегда с собой таскаю на флешке Leadertask. Стоит попробовать разные версии. С год назад в последней была проблема с базой данных, и с импортом-экспортом.